# Finish activity without waiting for completion

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I've been a bit tormented by finding out a way to finish an activity without waiting for it to complete.
I know that a simple "return;" statement will do the trick but in my architecture I can't do it.

I currently have:

```
public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
               finish();
               return;
          }
     }
}
```

and

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseFragmentActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          /* code still executed here even when parent finish(); is called */
     }
}
```

How can I prevent the execution of the code in MainActivity once the finish() in my abstract class is called?

UPDATED CODE:

```
public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
               finish();
               return;
          }
     }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseFragmentActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          if (isFinishing()) {
              return;
          }
     }
}
```

Strange thing though, the "return" seems to work, but my FragmentManager somehow launches the fragment at the end.

Comment: are you calling super.onCreate() in MainActivity?

Comment: Yes I am. It's actually the very first line. I'll update that in the question.

Comment: @Tomap why is it abstract class? also it should be .call super before if. Also check the note at the end of the page http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: I have abstract parent methods required for the lifecycle of my application. Thanks for the "super" call, I fixed that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in

```
if(isFinishing()){

    //code you don't want to execute if finish() is called

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for.
I updated my answer with my code.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you create a boolean and set it true and finish will be triggered ?

```
boolean end = false;
```

here you make it true

```
public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
end = true;
     }
}
```

and then use if statement

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseFragmentActivity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if(end = false){
//stuff here}
else {
finish();
}
     }
}
```

Comment: I actually thought about instantiating an abstract boolean attribute in the parent class, but I was hoping that I missed a method that already exists and does the very thing I require.
If I don't get the answer I'm looking for, I'll validate your reply. :)

Comment: The boolean value I was looking for is what triggs answered. I made your comment useful and I'll validate his response. :)